# Gradle application plugin run task with System.in runs out of Heap space

Tags: java, gradle

I'm processing 10 GB from `System.in` but consistently run out of heapspace when using the gradle application plugin. I'm piping the output of one program into java like so `mawk -f preprocess-logs.awk logs.txt | ./gradlew run` but continuously encounter the following error around 2 million lines processed( ~1GB consumed memory when seen from `htop`)

> expiring daemon because jvm tenured space is exhausted

My `build.gradle` (excluding unneeded parts) is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.PostgresLogLoader"
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

and I consume `System.in` with a BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line; 
while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null){ /* do work */ }
```

If I build the executable jar and use directly, I never run out of heap space. It appears the way I am consuming `standardInput` is growing unbounded. I'd prefer to not have to build an executable each time I want to run and continue running with `./gradlew run`. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you running the 64-bit JVM? I have ran into memory exhaustion issues when running 32-bit JVM and processing 1GB+ of data. Changing to the 64-bit JVM resolved the problem.